# webform submission to views of content

Tags: views, webforms, datetime

Suppose I build a webform with only a date picker and a submit button.
After I pick a date and click on the submit button, it takes me to a page
with a list of movie title, the date the movie released and the time interval in days (between the date I picked and the date the movie released).

For example, I picked 11/23/1995 and clicked submit; the result page will show a list.

- Titanic 11/1/1997 **709 days**
- Fight Club 10/15/1999 **1421 days**
- The Shawshank Redemption 09/23/1994 **426 days**

I want to display the time since the release in a view.

Comment: Hi, movila.  Welcome to Drupal answers!  Could you add to your question a little bit?  I'm not sure what you're asking exactly...

Comment: Film information are all nodes?

Comment: Why are you using a webform? It sounds to me like it should be an exposed filter on a view.

Comment: I'm really a newbie to drupal. I heard that VIEW is good at presenting list of data that retrieved from database and can put these data in order. I want to use data module to store the movies' names and their released dates. And display these data with a user interactive date picker to show above example list in Views module

Comment: As Sibiraj PR asked, if film information are nodes then you can simply add a time field there and can retrieve that time as field in your view to display

Comment: Thank you Sibiraj PR and Fahad. I got the movie list by making them nodes. But still don't know how to display  the time since the released date. Do I need to modify Views module to achieve this?